# Default permissions on OS/X when downloading from Chrome

Tags: macos, file-management, file-permissions, osx-yosemite

When I download an image or a file from Chrome, there are no Read rights on the Others group.

Would it be possible to change that, or would there be a way to make all files in a specific folder inherit the folder permissions?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

find the file, then highlight it and use the following shortcut: CMD-I. This will give you the info for the file. Close to the bottom of the Get Info window, there should be a permissions tab. Add the users/groups you want selected. the other option is to use the following scripting,

OK, there are a few ways to do this, although I am skipping the stand-alone script because that won't save any keystrokes. I also included that Unixy goodness, if you prefer that (just change the commented statements as desired):

//1) this script will change the permissions of the document files selected in the Finder - you can put it in the Finders toolbar:

```
    tell application "Finder"
    set these_items to the selection
    repeat with some_item in these_items
    if class of some_item is document file then -- don't change folders, etc
        -- do shell script "chmod +w " & quoted form of POSIX path of (some_item as text)
     set owner privileges of some_item to read write
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

//2) attach this folder action to a folder so that any file added to the folder gets the permission changed:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
repeat with some_item in these_items
    -- do shell script "chmod +w " & quoted form of POSIX path of (some_item as text)
    tell application "Finder" to set owner privileges of some_item to read write
end repeat
```

end adding folder items to

Comment: I want to make sure all files automatically have the permissions I want, I know how to manually change the permissions .

Comment: Try creating an Automator script to change the file permissions in the downloads folder.

Comment: I don't know how to do such a thing, if you add it to your answer then I'll accept it ! thanks